# recvfrom () does not work when data arrives

Tags: c, linux, windows, sockets, udp

I am working with sockets between different operating systems: Windows client and Linux server.
I have already managed to make a stable communication between them, but when running the server on another device (with the same operating system and creation of the identical server executable) it turns out that the recvfrom () function of the server does not work and the program blocks me.
I tried to change port: it does not work
I have tried to take this code to the other device: it does not work.
I have tracked the network traffic with Wireshark: the packets are sent perfectly to the IP of the server from the client. The server packages sent to the client are sent correctly.

I do not know what may be failing. The compiler does not report any problems, and I have not changed any code with respect to the application I had in the other device, simply the structure that I send now has 2 parameters (int + float) and the one before had 3 parameters (int + 2float).

I hope that someone can help me, thank you very much.

Server (LINUX) code:

```
bzero((char *)&rc_server.dir_serv,sizeof(rc_server.dir_serv));
rc_server.dir_serv.sin_family=AF_INET;
rc_server.dir_serv.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(DIR_UDP_U12);
rc_server.dir_serv.sin_port=htons(PORT_UDP_U12);

if((rc_server.sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0))<0)
    printf("Servidor:no puedo abrir socket\n\n");
else
    printf("Servidor: Socket creado correctamente\n");

if(bind(rc_server.sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&rc_server.dir_serv,sizeof(rc_server.dir_serv))<0)
{
    printf("Servidor: no se puede asociar la direccion local. Error en bind()\n\n");
    errorbind=1;
}
else
printf("Servidor: bind realizado correctamente\n");


// Bloqueo en espera del centro remoto
printf("\n\n------Servidor: preparado para recibir datos------\nEjecute aplicación en el cliente.\n\n\n");
i = recvfrom(rc_server.sockfd,(char*)&rc_server.receive_data,sizeof(comm_data_t),0,(struct sockaddr *)&rc_server.dir_cli,&rc_server.long_dir_cli);  // NO_RT!
printf("Valor de retorno de revfrom(): %d\n\n\n", i);
```

Client (WINDOWS) code:

```
#if defined WIN32
WSADATA wsaData;
int iResult;
iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != 0)
    printf("error en WSASturtup\n");
else
    printf("Winsock iniciado correctamente\n");
#endif
#if defined(RT)

int n=0;

/* Cliente para la comunicación con el robot */
memset((char *)&client.dir_serv, 0, sizeof(client.dir_serv));

client.dir_serv.sin_family=AF_INET;
client.dir_serv.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(DIR_UDP_U12); 
client.dir_serv.sin_port=htons(PORT_UDP_U12);

if((client.sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0))<0)
    printf("Cliente: no puedo abrir socket con el ROBOT");
else
    printf("Socket creado correctamente\n\n\n\n");


/* Envio de señal de comienzo al robot */
n=sendto(client.sockfd, (char *)&client.send_data, sizeof(comm_data_t), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client.dir_serv, sizeof(client.dir_serv));
if(n<0)
{
    perror("dg_cli: error en el sendto\n");
    printf("n = %d\n\nWSAerror = %d\n\n", n, WSAGetLastError());
}
else
    printf("Primer mensaje enviado\n\n\n");
```

In the client application I am sending data periodically, not only is the first sendto (), there are many more. As I said, the data is sent correctly, but on the server the recvfrom () function does not detect the arrival of any package.

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: This implies that the server is probably `bind`'ing to the wrong IP that is different than the IP that the client is sending to.  What is the actual value of `DIR_UDP_U12`, and is it an IP that actually belongs to the server device? Are the client and server on the same LAN network, or are you sending datagrams over the Internet? What is the source IP of the datagrams being sent from the server to the client, and does that IP match what the client is sending to?

Comment: The actual value of DIR_UDP_U12 is the IP associated with the server device.
Both devices are on the same LAN. I have made connections between different operating systems within the same LAN without problems.
When I used Wireshark I saw that the IP addresses (both client and server) were correct when sending data.
I have also verified that access is possible from one device to another (client ping server and server ping client).

I know the error is in the recvfrom (), because the 'printf()' that there is after doesn't appear in the terminal when I execute the server application.

Comment: I only error I see in the `recvfrom()` code is maybe `rc_server.long_dir_cli` being uninitialized (it is an in/out parameter, so i must be initialized beforehand). Have you tried checking with `select()` or `(e)poll()` to make sure the server socket is actually entering a readable state before you then call `recvfrom()`? If they don't report the socket receiving inbound data, then it makes sense that `recvfrom()` would block waiting for data that doesn't arrive.

Comment: Yes I initialize the value of that variable, in the following way: `rc_server.long_dir_cli = sizeof (rc_server.dir_cli)`
dir_cli is of type `struct sockaddr_in`.
Yes, I have checked that the server opens the socket and stays listening in the port I have set (6500)

Comment: I didn't ask if the server opens the socket, I asked if `select()`/`(e)poll()` are able to detect data on the socket before calling `recvfrom()`. Did you check that yet? It is important.

Comment: I do not know how to do that. What should I put in the code to check what you tell me? And what should I observe once included what you tell me?